# pyAudio input seems lagging when using after some "idle" time

Tags: python, pyaudio, raspberry-pi-zero

I'm prototyping some small project of mine and encountered a small problem, I need help to fix it.

The project is a little "walkie-talkie" raspberry pi project. I'm using a raspberry pi zero, a mic-hat & python. The scripts connect to a mumble server and when the mic-hat button is pressed, the raspberry sends the voice to the mumble server

Everything works so far. But when everything is up and running and no one is using the raspberry pi for some time, and the user is coming back, pushing the button to send some voice, it seems that pyAudio needs some short time, to get the mic working. It lags for 2 seconds. After the lag, everything works fine again and response instantly.

I think, that the problem is pyAudio, because the raspberry pi and the pymumble part response instantly, even after some idle time.

So I'm providing my WIP code (removed connection information) and maybe someone can explain why this behavior is happing.

```
#!/home/pi/mic_hat/.venv/bin/python

import pymumble_py3 as pymumble
from pymumble_py3.callbacks import PYMUMBLE_CLBK_SOUNDRECEIVED as PCS
from pymumble_py3.callbacks import PYMUMBLE_CLBK_CONNECTED as PCCONNECTED
from pymumble_py3.callbacks import PYMUMBLE_CLBK_DISCONNECTED as PCDISCONNECTED

import pyaudio
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

BUTTON = 17
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(BUTTON, GPIO.IN)

SERVERIP = "" # server address
SERVERPORT = 0 # port number
NICKNAME = ""

from apa102_pi.driver import apa102
import time

# Initialize the library and the strip
strip = apa102.APA102(num_led=3, global_brightness=20, mosi=10, sclk=11,
                      order='rgb')

# Turn off all pixels (sometimes a few light up when the strip gets power)
strip.clear_strip()

# Prepare a few individual pixels
# strip.set_pixel_rgb(LED #, Color Value)
strip.set_pixel_rgb(0, 0xFF0000)  # Red
strip.set_pixel_rgb(1, 0xFFFF00)  # Yellow
strip.set_pixel_rgb(2, 0x00FF00)  # Green

def user_count_is_1():
    strip.set_pixel_rgb(1, 0xFFFF00, 0)  # Yellow
    strip.show()

def user_count_is_2():
    strip.set_pixel_rgb(1, 0xFFFF00, 10)  # Yellow
    strip.show()

def user_is_sending_voice():
    strip.set_pixel_rgb(2, 0x00FF00, 100)  # Green
    strip.show()

def user_is_not_sending_voice():
    strip.set_pixel_rgb(2, 0x00FF00, 0)  # Green
    strip.show()

def device_is_connected_to_the_server():
    strip.set_pixel_rgb(0, 0xFF0000, 10)  # Red
    strip.show()

def device_is_disconnected_from_the_server():
    strip.set_pixel_rgb(0, 0xFF0000, 0)  # Red
    strip.show()

# Connection details for mumble server.
pwd = ""  # password
server = SERVERIP  # server address
nick = NICKNAME
port = SERVERPORT  # port number
RESPEAKER_INDEX = 1

# pyaudio set up
CHUNK = 512 #1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16  # pymumble soundchunk.pcm is 16 bits
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 48000  # pymumble soundchunk.pcm is 48000Hz

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

input_stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,  # enable both talk
        frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

output_stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                output=True,  # and listen
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK,
                output_device_index = RESPEAKER_INDEX)


# mumble client set up
def sound_received_handler(user, soundchunk):
    """ play sound received from mumble server upon its arrival """
    output_stream.write(soundchunk.pcm)

# Spin up a client and connect to mumble server
mumble = pymumble.Mumble(server, nick, password=pwd, port=port, reconnect=True)
# set up callback called when PCS event occurs
mumble.callbacks.set_callback(PCS, sound_received_handler)
mumble.callbacks.set_callback(PCCONNECTED, device_is_connected_to_the_server)
mumble.callbacks.set_callback(PCDISCONNECTED, device_is_disconnected_from_the_server)
mumble.set_receive_sound(1)  # Enable receiving sound from mumble server
mumble.start()
mumble.is_ready()  # Wait for client is ready

# capturing sound and sending it to mumble server when button is pressed
try:
    while True:
        state = GPIO.input(BUTTON)
        user_count = mumble.users.count()
        if user_count == 2:
            user_count_is_2()
        else:
            user_count_is_1()
        if not state:
            user_is_sending_voice()
            data = input_stream.read(CHUNK, exception_on_overflow=False)
            mumble.sound_output.add_sound(data)
        else:
            user_is_not_sending_voice()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("\nCtrl+C detected. Exiting...")
    print("Cleaning up resources.")
    # close the stream and pyaudio instance
    strip.cleanup()
    input_stream.stop_stream()
    input_stream.close()
    p.terminate()
```

So I tried to deactivate the WLAN power management of the raspberry pi, but that did not solved the problem. The pymumble Server logic is running instantly. So it seems that the problem is pyAudio related. Maybe it has something to do with buffer??

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).